# about using a library project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-library, library-project

I have developed an Android library project, let's call it **MyLibProject**.

For example, a class in **MyLibProject**:

```
public class MyLibClass {
  ...
  public void doTask() {...}

}
```

Then, I start to develop an Android **App project** which uses the classes in **MyLibProject**.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyLibClass myLib = new MyLibClass();
        myLib.doTask();
    }
}
```

In Eclipse, I could choose one of the following ways to make above things working:

**1st Way:** Right click **MyLibProject** ==> properties==> in `Android` section, tick `isLibrary` to mark it as a library project. Then, in **App project**, add **MyLibProject** as a library project.

**2nd Way**: Right click **App Project** ==> properties==> Java build path, select `Projects` tab , add **MyLibProject** ==> click OK.

My question is, What are the differences of these two ways ? I mean, in Eclipse, what are the differences BETWEEN adding a library project to `Library` section of `Android` property AND adding the library project to java build path? Should I do both?

Answer (score 1):

The 1st way is the official way in Eclipse to create and use an Android library project.

The 2nd way is for compilation dependencies (it adds another Eclipse project as a build dependency of your project), and is not specific to Android.

You only need to do the first.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get it more clear, do you mean I could use either way? Nothing harmful if I use 2nd way in my case right?

Comment: @Leem.fin I never tried the 2nd way for an Android library project, but I don't think it will work.

Comment: Well, I tired the 2nd way, seems it is fine, but I'd like to hear more if it might not work, what could be the root reason.

Comment: no you can't use the second way, because android is gonna add the dependency for you automatically. If you do it, in the best case, the application will crash for duplicate dex entries

Comment: @Leem.fin Did you just try to build it this way, or did you actually try to run the application using the library on a device?

Comment: @Eran, I tried run the app. Why would it cause duplicate dex entries ? I mean if I only add the library project in java build path without adding it as a "Library" project? Where does the duplication come?

Comment: @Leem.fin I think if you don't add the project as an Android library project, your app wouldn't have the resources defined in the library project. Therefore you must add it the first way.

Comment: @Eran, that is a good reason to use 1st way. I should mention in my question that I only use java class in Library project, if that is the case, what problem(s) could be caused by 2nd way?